# Exporting to 3ds without smoothing

Tags: export

First I'm not a 3D modeler and I cant change the geometry of the model. Can I export to a .3ds without smoothing? Smoothing is causing tons of issues in my model (shading issues). I want it to just look like it does when it's flat (when viewing inside of blender). Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Hi, where/how are you looking at the exported model?

Comment: @m.ardito Inside of our own renderer (OpenGL).

Answer (score 1):

This object is badly designed, imho :) but it surely can be fixed!

I guess it comes from a vector import (cad maybe) but even if blender in solid mode does a decent job of displaying it, this mesh has many flaws. You shouldn't believe me, you should believe the numbers.

Numbers: your model has 70% duplicated verts. A simple "remove doubles" reduces your 38287 verts to 11504!You have 26783 doubles...

But it's not all, imho: in wireframe mode you can even see many weird edges here and there, but to get more numbers, I used the bundled "3d print toolbox", which makes easy to find mesh problems.

Here the result **after** removing doubles...

[image]

Since we know nothing about your "own renderer (OpenGL)" it could be this one to visually show the model weird, probably due to many issues in the model. If you could post a picture of the model in that renderer something could perhaps be guessed...

Answer (score 0):

You can always make faces to look sharp, just select the object, go to  Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>, select the faces and then on the left panel (press <kbd>T</kbd> to open it) you can find a tab callled *Shading / UV* -> *Faces* -> and click *Flat*.

[image]

Comment: Kaderabek I've tried this but I receive the exact same output. I'll play with it more. What I don't gt is why is what I see in Blender so different than the output?

Comment: Can you attach you .blend file via this link? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I attached file to original post. Thanks!

Comment: I cant see any, I have exported it to 3ds and imported ... it looks just exactly the same. How can I reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you upload the .3ds to me? We are using our own renderer to view the .3ds file. Example if you open my original blender file exmaple.blend in Blender. If you select all the faces and set the shading/uvs to smooth. You should see the issue I am getting when I export to .3ds and bring into our software.

Comment: The main issue is the geometry (topology) is really untidy - lots of overlapping edges / faces etc, I tried Remove Doubles and it removes over 26k vertices .... try to make some really simple scene with the tool you used for creating the scene and make sure you don't have problem right from the beginning. Unfortunately I am not sure what to do with such complex scene without time consuming manual retopology, sorry :-/

Comment: no worries and thank you for taking the time to look at it, I really do appreciate the help.